# Parsing lambda to a function using templates

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

I am quite new to C++ and I am currently trying to learn how to utilize a  template for a lambda function.

The lambda can be seen in the `main` function, and it simply makes a boolean check.

The implementation below works, but I have to explicitly state the types of the lambda in the `testing` function, as seen in the input parameter.

```
void testing(std::function<bool(const int& x)> predicate){
    auto a = predicate(2);
    std::cout << a << "\n";
}

int main() {
    int ax = 2;
    testing([&ax](const int& x) { return x == ax;});
}
```

I wish for an implementation where I can utilize templates as seen below, but I can not get anything to work.

```
template <typename T>
void testing(std::function<bool(const T& x)> predicate){
    auto a = predicate(2);
    std::cout << a << "\n";
}
```

Is there a general way to utilize a template for lambdas?

Comment: You could do `T predicate`.

Comment: What version of C++ are you on? C++14 gives you some really nice lambda features

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Don't wrap the template parameter in `std::function`.

The best way to pass a lambda to a function is to just have it as an unconstrained template parameter:

```
template<class F>
void testing(F predicate) {
    auto a = predicate(2); 
    std::cout << a << '\n';
}

int main() {
    int ax = 2;
    testing([ax](int x) { return x == ax; }); 
}
```

#### Benefits over `std::function`.

- `std::function` allocates space on the heap to store the functor
- `std::function` has an overhead similar to a virtual function call
- `std::function` can't be inlined by the compiler, but it's trivial to inline a lambda that's passed directly

Comment: In this case, the template solution is definitely better. But sometimes std::function comes handy. For example if you want to keep a function as a member of a class instance. Then std::function is often the better solution if the drawbacks of std::function are not a concern. The whole class then does not have to be a template.